# About the function of the word everything

Tags: grammar

> We watch the sun set from the lip of the canyon, overlooking a
>   rectangular structure that looks everything like an ancient apartment
>   building.

I'm posting this question, being not sure how to analyze the word "everything" in the sentence in the yellow box as an adverb or a noun and if it's used as an adverb, what does everything modify? Looks or like?
I think everything adverbially modifies the verb "looks".

So my questions are..

1. What do you think of my analysis of the word everything?
2. Is the sentence grammatical and natural-sounding?

Comment: "Everything" is a compound **determinative**. Yes, the sentence is grammatical and natural considering its literary use.

Answer (score 1):

"Everything" here isn't a noun. It's used like "a lot". You can say "a rectangular structure that looks *a lot* like an ancient apartment building". Here, "everything" is just an "upgraded" version of "a lot".

> ... "looks everything like an ancient apartment building."

This means that *everything* about the "rectangular structure" looks like "an ancient apartment building". The walls, doors, ceiling, etc. *Everything* in/on the "rectangular structure" looks like something in/on an "ancient apartment building".